# Изменение данных формы в процессе валидации

Tags: javascript, html

Есть форма с функцией проверки на валидацию.

Как только вы нажали отправить, функция срабатывает и находит неверное поле. Пользователю об этом сообщается в  виде всплывающего окна, там же можно изменить значение.

После этого получается, что нужно вернуть `false` на валидаторе и пользователю снова нажать отправить. Даже если обновляем данные в нужном поле - для формы они все равно остаются прежними и это логично.

Можно ли как-то обновить данные для формы на этом этапе?

Код для примера:

```
<form onsubmit="return valid();">
    <input name="test" id="test1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
    function valid(){
        validVar = true;
        if($('#test1').val()==1)){
            $('#test1').val(2);
        }
    return validVar;
    }
</script>
```

Такой код отправит в форму 1, если ввели 1, как отправить 2?

Comment: "если обновляем данные в нужном поле - для формы они все равно остаются прежними" - пример?

Comment: Так и должно быть, сами рассудите - данные перешли в форму и ждут отправки, мы проверяем их. В процессе проверки меняем содержимое поля, но ведь для форы они остались прежними, если мы отменим отправку валидатором, то да, они обновятся, но если вернем, что все хорошо - не важно что написано в поле, данные уже подготовленны и теперь полетят на сервер

Comment: "данные перешли в форму" - смысл этой фразы от меня ускользает.  Покажите код.

Comment: Сейчас добавлю пример